# SQL Select with 2 foreign key referencing on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

i have a table that contains a 
    user: ID,Name,UserName
and a table that contains an
    event:ID,AskerID,DoerID,EventName
I need to get the name of the Asker using AskerID but I already have a left outer join 
that get the doer one

I'm not very good with sql ...a little help is always welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can like one table to other tables based on different ChildKeys (AskerID, DoerID).

```
Select
 a.Name as Asker
 , d.Name as Doer
 , e.EventName
from event as e
left outer join user as a
on e.AskerID = a.ID
left outer join user as d
on e.DoerID = d.ID
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i was trying to do!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the table with the user is called `Users` and the table with the event is called `Events`:

```
select   e.ID
         e.AskerID
         a.Name as AskerName
         e.DoerID
         d.Name as DoerName
         e.EventName
from     Events e
   left join Users a
          on e.AskerID = a.ID
   left join Users d
          on e.DoerID = d.ID
```

You can left join (or inner join) to the same table more than once: you just have to give one or both of them aliases.  That's what the `a`, `e`, and `d` are.  You may also want to rename some of the fields:  that's why I renamed `a.Name` to `AskerName` and `d.Name` to `DoerName`.

Answer (score 0):

It goes like this,

```
SELECT E.*, U1.ID AS DOERID, U2.ID AS ASKERID
FROM AS EVENT AS E
LEFT JOIN USER AS U1
ON E.DOERID = U1.ID
LEFT JOIN USER AS U2
ON E.ASKERID = U2.ID
```